# Run OS X 10.6 virtual machine on macOS 11 with UTM

Tags: snow-leopard, virtualization

How do I configure the app [UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) with Mac OS X Snow Leopard as a guest operating system?

Here is what I have:

- macOS 11.6

  - Running on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
- UTM 2.2.4 (36)
- Mac OS X 10.6 install ISO file (snow leopard install.iso)

Comment: The only thing close to a tutorial I have found is a walkthrough to install Snow Leopard on the iPad build of UTM. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuhMeHoGa_M

Comment: I am not sure what your requirements are. I will post that I have Snow Leopard 10.6.8 running in VirtualBox 6.1.26 on a iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013). The iMac has Catalina 10.15.7 installed. VirtualBox is a free product. I mention this in case your only requirement is Snow Leopard running in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 5):

https://khronokernel.github.io/apple/silicon/2021/01/17/QEMU-AS.html

I'm working on getting 10.4 x86 through 12 running in UTM; so far, the recalcitrant ones have been 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 11 and 12:

https://github.com/adespoton/utmconfigs/blob/main/README.md

I've got UTM config files on there for all other OS Versions (10.7 through 10.15).

For 10.6, I'm stuck during boot; no matter whether I use Chameleon, iBoot, OpenCore i386 or OpenCore x86_64, I end up frozen at a grey-on-grey apple boot screen, with verbose mode not showing up even when I've explicitly set it, either in the boot plist or in the QEMU parameters.

But it should definitely be possible; the wrong hardware is being presented and/or the DSDT is set wrong.

But I can create a VM in VirtualBox on an x86-64 Mac using one of these hackintosh methods, and it boots fine.  Copy it over to my M1, try to boot it via UTM, and... hang at apple.

Next step is to try via M1 homebrew qemu, and see if rolling the config by hand without SPICE etc. will change anything.

This doesn't fully answer the question, but it answers it up to a point where maybe someone can find the last few missing pieces.

[edit] worth noting, that YouTube link in the comments is a known fake -- it says it's Snow Leopard, but really they're running Leopard PPC (which works just fine; I've got 9.0.4 through 10.5.6 PPC working fine in UTM, which uses the qemu-system-ppc-screamer fork instead of stable qemu-system-ppc, which enables audio but breaks snapshots).

[edit 2] Still trying to sort this out.  Latest 3.1b build of UTM fixes a bunch of things that bring this closer to booting, but still no luck getting past that first hang using Penryn CPU and either OpenCore i386 or OpenCore x86_64.  DSDTs don't seem to be the problem, and I've played around with a number of OpenCore kernel options and they haven't made a difference either.

Good news is, UTM is now happily running Mac OS 9.1 through 10.5.x PPC, 10.7.x through 11.x x86_64 and 12.x AARCH.  There's been some sort of regression with 9.0.4, and 10.4.x through 10.6.x i386 and x86_64 still aren't booting.  There were no changes in QEMU between 3.0.4 and 3.1, so this is likely a SPICE or UTM issue with 9.0.4.  The other previously-broken OSes had USB bus issues -- 10.0-10.1 used CUDA and UTM was trying to insert USB instead causing the ADB handlers to be disconnected, and macOS 11 was seeing the presented USB bus and rejecting it, leaving the user with no input devices.  Both these are now fixed.